# Set data on PrimaryContentViewController and DrawerContentViewController from my HomeViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using [Pulley](https://github.com/52inc/Pulley) where I am using below code to open the PulleyViewController.

```
func openEventInfoPage(event : EventsModel,indexPath:NSIndexPath){
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PulleyViewController")
            as! PulleyViewController

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Here, while opening the **PulleyViewController** I also need to send data to both **DrawerContentViewController** and **PrimaryContentViewController**. **How should I do that?**

Its nowhere mentioned on Github, I tried making object of both the classes and sending data before Pushing PulleyViewController but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I came out with the following solution and it worked perfectly.

```
    let mainContentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrimaryContentViewController") as! PrimaryContentViewController

    mainContentVC.event = event
    mainContentVC.indexPath = indexPath

    let drawerContentVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerContentViewController") as! DrawerContentViewController
    drawerContentVC.event = event

    let pulleyDrawerVC = PulleyViewController(contentViewController: mainContentVC, drawerViewController: drawerContentVC)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(pulleyDrawerVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property on `DrawerContentViewController`. like - `aProperty` as open property. And assign value of aProperty on your `DrawerContentViewController` -

```
func openEventInfoPage(event : EventsModel,indexPath:NSIndexPath){
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PulleyViewController") as! PulleyViewController 
        let vc2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DrawerContentViewController") as! DrawerContentViewController

         vc2.aProperty = "value"

        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```